# Indenting subsection - Error: Entered in horizontal mode

Tags: sectioning, errors, indentation, titlesec

I've seen others similar questions but they really did not help. I'm very new to LaTeX.

This is the problematic text:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
    \titleformat*{\subsection}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\bfseries\large}
    \subsection*{Test}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

I want to indent a subsection/section. Text generation is okay, but I get this error. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `\titlepacing*` command which is useful here: it has 3 arguments, the first one being used for a possible indent of the heading, the other two for the vertical spacing before and after the heading. I used the simplified syntax, explained in § 3.2 Spacing of the dpcumentation:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \titlespacing*{\subsection}{-0.5cm}{*3.5}{*1.5}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
    \subsection*{Test}
    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you both. I dunno why I did not see the \titlespacing command.

Answer (score 1):

The correct command to indent the subsection title is actually the `\titlespacing` command. See the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) of `titlesec` for more information. For example,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\large}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{\parindent}{2mm}{2mm}
\begin{document}
    \subsection*{Test}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]